# Regarding navigation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to move the  pr2 robot in a particular path specified (example to move in lane)
Can anyone suggest how  to proceed ?

Thanks in Advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49496/regarding-navigation/) by [telxsipr2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3356/telxsipr2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you really want to stick to a path, you could use the [pose_follower](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pose_follower) or [pose_follower_3d](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pose_follower_3d) packages.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1